# Add abbreviated data type to SOAP request body elements

Tags: ruby, xml, soap, savon

I'm trying to build a SOAP request using the Savon (version 2).

This is how the request XML should look:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <cred_LogIn xmlns="http://webservice.dz-manager.com/">
      <sUsername>string</sUsername>
      <sPassword>string</sPassword>
      <sConsumerIdent>string</sConsumerIdent>
    </cred_LogIn>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

When I do this:

```
client = Savon.client(
    wsdl: 'https://online-tools.dz-manager.com/Services/DzM_WebService.asmx?WSDL',
    soap_version: 2,
    pretty_print_xml: true,
    env_namespace: 'soap12',
    namespace_identifier: nil,
    log_level: :debug)

client.call(:cred_log_in,
            message:
              {username: 'my_username',
               password: 'my_password',
               consumer_ident: 'DZ-Manager_Web-Service_Consumer'},
            attributes: {
               xmlns: 'http://webservice.dz-manager.com/'}
)
```

Savon builds the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://webservice.dz-manager.com/" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <cred_LogIn xmlns="http://webservice.dz-manager.com/">
      <username>my_username</username>
      <password>my_password</password>
      <consumerIdent>DZ-Manager_Web-Service_Consumer</consumerIdent>
    </cred_LogIn>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Which is nearly the desired result. The only difference is the message elements should be prefixed with 's', e.g.: `<username>` should be `<sUsername>`. This 's' presumably means 'string' as I find 'int' (i.e. integer) and 'l' (i.e. long) in other operations.

Is there a hidden option in Savon to prepend message elements with an abbreviaton of their data types? And if not: how can I make sure the elements are prefixed with their data type abbreviations?

Changing the keys in the value for `message` doesn't work: `s_username: 'my-username'` of `'sUsername' => 'my-username'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [documentation](http://savonrb.com/version2/locals.html) and the [source](https://github.com/savonrb/savon/blob/97f1d94bf3c6c60a1c74a989c15978a0f411588e/lib/savon/envelope.rb#L51) I came up with the following solution:

```
class ServiceRequest

  def to_s
    builder = Builder::XmlMarkup.new

    builder.tag! :sUsername, "my_username"
    builder.tag! :sPassword, "my_password"
    builder.tag! :sConsumerIdent, "DZ-Manager_Web-Service_Consumer"

    builder
  end

end
```

And then in the terminal:

```
client = Savon.client(
    wsdl: 'https://online-tools.dz-manager.com/Services/DzM_WebService.asmx?WSDL',
    soap_version: 2,
    pretty_print_xml: true,
    env_namespace: 'soap12',
    namespace_identifier: nil,
    log_level: :debug)

client.call(:cred_log_in,
            message: ServiceRequest.new,
            attributes: {
               xmlns: 'http://webservice.dz-manager.com/'}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use strings for your message hash. You might also want to change the function call.

```
client.call('cred_LogIn',
        message:
          { 'sUsername': 'my_username',
            'sPassword': 'my_password',
            'sConsumerIdent': 'DZ-Manager_Web-Service_Consumer'},
        attributes: {
           xmlns: 'http://webservice.dz-manager.com/'}
)
```

Comment: It should be `'sUsername' => 'my_username'` else I get a syntax error. And I already tried that, it builds the message elements like this: `<xmlns:sUsername>my_username</xmlns:sUsername>`. Also I get an error when the operation name is (`cred_LogIn`) not a symbol.